# Python code to to extract contents between multiple "start" and "end"

Tags: python

I am an absolute newbie to python. I have multiple news articles within one text file and there are 2000+ text files. Each news article starts with "Dow Jones Newswires DJDN" and ends with "(END) Dow Jones Newswires".

There is a set of code extracting every contents between multiple "start" and "end" like this:

```
with open('./news_txt/A_2013.txt') as infile, open('./news_txt/A_2013_a.txt', 'w') as outfile:
copy = False
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "Dow Jones Newswires DJDN":
        copy = True
        continue
    elif line.strip() == "(END) Dow Jones Newswires":
        copy = False
        continue
    elif copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```

However, this code only applies to the situation in which 1) there is only one txt file; 2) all the extracted contents are store in a new txt file.

But what I want is 1) loop every txt files in a path; 2) each extracted content is being saved in a new txt file.

For example, if there are 10 news in a txt, after running the code I should get 10 new txt files storing each news.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os, os.path
folder_path = './news_txt'

def num_to_letters(n):
    rs=[]
    while n >0:
         n-=1
         n,r = divmod(n,26)
         rs.insert(0,chr(r+ord('a')))
    return ''.join(rs)

for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if not file_name.lower().endswith('.txt'):
        continue
    in_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,file_name)
    
    
    with open(in_file_path,'r') as in_file:
        out_file = None
        num_out_files = 0
        for line in in_file:
            if line.strip() == "Dow Jones Newswires DJDN":
                if out_file is None:
                    num_out_files +=1
                    out_file_name = file_name[:-4]+'_'+num_to_letters(num_out_files)+'.txt'
                    out_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,out_file_name)
                    out_file = open(out_file_path,'w')
                continue
            elif line.strip() == "(END) Dow Jones Newswires":
                if out_file is not None:
                    out_file.close()
                    out_file = None
                continue
            elif out_file is not None:
                out_file.write(line)
        if out_file is not None:
            out_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! It seems that this does not save each extracted content in a separate txt files. What I need is if there are 10 extracted articles, there should be file_name_a.txt, file_name_b.txt ...... to file_name_j.txt. Cheers!!

Comment: @jack1002021 ah I didn't get that from the question. Let me adjust my answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply again! Sorry for bothering you but problems are still there. Let say I have two files in a folder and they are A_2013.txt and A_2014.txt. The code only returns a file called "A_2013_.txt" with several "Dow Jones Newswires DJDN" in it.

Comment: @jack1002021 The underscore without the a - did you use the latest edit from 18 min ago? num_out_files should be incremented to 1 before calling num_to_letters(), which should return a. For multiple articles being contained in one file, are you sure that "(END) Dow Jones Newswires" is the EXACT end of article delimiter? Is it guaranteed to be on its own line?

Comment: I used the latest code. Now only one file "A_2013_a.txt" appears. Inside, there are only 
"
Dow Jones Newswires DJDN
Dow Jones Newswires DJDN
Dow Jones Newswires DJDN
Dow Jones Newswires DJDN
Dow Jones Newswires DJDN
Dow Jones Newswires DJDN
Dow Jones Newswires DJDN
"
I guarantee that "(END) Dow Jones Newsires" is the exact end of article and it is on its own line.

Comment: I confirm the "start" and "end" work by using the code in my very first post.

Comment: @jack1002021 I had an indentation problem because believe it or not I'm typing all this code from my phone. The elifs were indented too far in

Comment: @jack1002021 is it in the same folder as the 2013 file? Does it end with .txt? Does it have the same start and end strings?

Comment: My mistake. I have a typo when making my own tweaks. 2013 and 2014 hope appear now!! Sorry for one more thing. Could you please help me to change the letter added to the end to number? Just think of a problem when the number of article within the main txt exceeds 26.

Comment: @jack1002021 The function I wrote at the top basically will go a,b,c,...,x,y,z,aa,ab,ac,...,az,ba,bb,...zz,aaa,...,etc - it is essentially an unsigned base 26 number representation. To do a number instead just replace "num_to_letters(num_out_files)" with "str(num_out_files).zfill(3)". This will put a three digit number i.e. 001, 002, ...

Comment: Perfect!!! Once again, thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and use a regular expression instead:

```
^Dow Jones Newswires DJDN.+?^\(END\) Dow Jones Newswires
```

With the modifiers `m` and `s`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sWBWGO/1/).